# Javascript onblur affect from text box input to iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, onblur

I am trying to type a url into a form text input, and onBlur, update the contents of an included iframe with the webpage specified in the url. I can't seem to get it to work and I can't figure out why... :)

Can someone help me ?

Here is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN” 
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″ />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
<!-- hide
function setIframeSource() {      
var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');      
var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe'); 
var theUrl;        
theUrl = document.getElementById("location");
theIframe.src = theUrl;
}
// end hide -->
</script>
</head>
<body><center>
<form id="form1" method="post">      
<input type="text" style="width:150px;" name="location2" id="location" onBlur="setIframeSource();">
</form>  
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="300"><iframe src="http://www.ibm.com" id="myIframe" width="280" height="300"   name="frame1"></iframe></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setIframeSource() {      
    var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');      
    var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe'); 
    var theUrl;        
    theUrl = document.getElementById("location");
    theIframe.src = theUrl;
}
```

Perhaps the problem is line 5 above -- it should read:

```
theUrl = document.getElementById("location").value;
```

Presently, you're assigning the input element itself to `theUrl`, which is not a valid value for `theIframe.src`!

Answer (score 1):

try adding this after you set the `iframe`'s `src`:

`theIframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true);`

and, get the value from the input:

`document.getElementById('location').value;`